# No response from my Url with json data

Tags: javascript, json

I tried to get response from my json url in javascript by using below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    //attach a jQuery live event to the button
    $('#getdata-button').live('click', function(){
        alert("get data"); 
        $.getJSON('http://vamdemo2.e-isg.com/vamsyncservices/api/site/GetAllSites?username=Admin&password=password', function(data) {  
            alert(" data alert"+data); //uncomment this for debug
        });
    });
});
```

I didn't got any response from above url. If I changed the url from http://vamdemo2.e-isg.com/vamsyncservices/api/site/GetAllSites?username=Admin&password=password to https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/en/bob_dylan, getting response. If I open the both url's in browser, both are having data.. But, when I tried to get response from  the url using javascript , one url only given response. Where is the problem?? Why another url not giving any response??

Please give me any solution for this...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Might be related to the same origin policy

Comment: Didn't get you clearly.. Can you plz give little more explanation.

Comment: Try to use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to see your network requests. Then you can look at the response code for your request. This would give you at least some information about the error. As a side note, do consider using `on` instead of `live` in `jQuery`, because `live` is currently deprecated.

Comment: I've tried it and keep getting a 407, but that might just be my school's proxy.

Comment: Thanks Asad, have you any idea, what's  the problem??

Comment: @Grampa, I tried in Chrome, in response it was showing as 'This request has no response data available'

Answer (score 1):

I've put your code in my browsers and, for me, both URLs are not working.

Even for the googleapis.com URL, when I load your code in chrome and press F12 I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/en/bob_dylan. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

This is because JavaScript typically is not allowed to run on domain1 and load URLs from domain2. This is by design, as a security measure.

If

-you are happy to change your client code above AND

-you can make your vamdemo2.e-isg.com server to alter the response when a "callback" query string parameter is added

Then

-there is a solution to this: JSONP

Read more details about how to implement this here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Type in your firefox address about:config then look for forcecors.headers string, maybe it works because you have a value of:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET

Comment: But I spent time to help you, so please accept again! Maybe you want to vote your question down to help other users?
I know why it works in your jQM app, please use .on instead of .live (deprecated)